# What are the ways to refresh a JButton with ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, repaint

As what the title says, is there any way I can repaint a `JButton` besides `repaint()`, `validate()`, and `invalidate()`? I have used those to repaint my JButton but it is still the same. Here is my code:

```
package buttonrepaint;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class Buttonrepaint {

JFrame Card = new JFrame();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray);

public static String buttonname;
public static String num1="";   public static String num2=""; public static String num3="";


public static int flagnum1=1, flagnum2=1, flagnum3=1;


JButton btn_1;  JButton btn_2;  JButton btn_3;


    static int buttonGroup=1;
int stat = 0;

   public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prodbutton = getProductsButton(buttonGroup);


public Buttonrepaint(){
        Card.setVisible(true);
    Card.setSize(522,500);
    Card.setTitle("Frequency Distribution");
    Card.setResizable(false);

    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
    int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth())/4);
    int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight())/2);

    Card.setLocation(x, y);
            Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    FlowLayout flow_1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,1,1);
    final JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel_1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    panel_1.setLayout(flow_1);

    final JButton btnGroup3 = new JButton("Next");
    //btnGroup3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\yellow.png"));
    //btnGroup3.setBorderPainted(false);  
           // btnGroup3.setFocusPainted(false);
           // btnGroup3.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
            btnGroup3.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    btnGroup3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnGroup3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    btnGroup3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            buttonGroup++;

            if(prodbutton==null)
            {
                btnGroup3.setText("Back");
                prodbutton.clear();
                stat=1;
                btn_1.invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("EMPTY!!!!!");
                buttonGroup--;
                stat=0;
            }


        }
    });
    panel_1.add(btnGroup3);
    try{
        num1=Capitalize(prodbutton.get(0).get("prodname"));

        if(prodbutton.get(0).get("butstatus").equals("0"))
        {flagnum1=0;}
    }catch (Exception e) 
        {flagnum1=0;}       

    try{
        num2=Capitalize(prodbutton.get(1).get("prodname"));

        if(prodbutton.get(1).get("butstatus").equals("0"))
        {flagnum2=0;}
    }catch (Exception e) 
        {flagnum2=0;}   

    try{
        num3=Capitalize(prodbutton.get(2).get("prodname"));

        if(prodbutton.get(2).get("butstatus").equals("0"))
        {flagnum3=0;}
    }catch (Exception e) 
        {flagnum3=0;}   


    btn_1 = new JButton("<html><p align=center>"+num1+"</p></html>");
    //btn_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\lightblue.png"));
    //btn_1.setBorderPainted(false);  
            //btn_1.setFocusPainted(false);
            //btn_1.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
            btn_1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    btn_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
    btn_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));

    if(flagnum1==0)
    {   btn_1.setEnabled(false);    }
    btn_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{

                if(flagnum1==1)
                {
                    if(num1!=null)
                    {
                        buttonname = prodbutton.get(0).get("prodname");
                        //quantity_panel qp = new quantity_panel();
                    }

                }
                if (stat==1)
                {

                    buttonname=buttonname;

                    //quantity_panel qp = new quantity_panel();
                }


            }catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Error~");}
        }
    });
    panel_1.add(btn_1);

    btn_2 = new JButton("<html><p align=center>"+num2+"</p></html>");
    //btn_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\lightblue.png"));
    //btn_2.setBorderPainted(false);  
           // btn_2.setFocusPainted(false);
           // btn_2.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
            btn_2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    btn_2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
    btn_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));

    if(flagnum2==0)
    {   btn_2.setEnabled(false);    }

    btn_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try{
                if(flagnum2==1)
                {
                    if(num2!=null)
                    {
                        buttonname = prodbutton.get(1).get("prodname");
                        //quantity_panel qp = new quantity_panel();
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
    panel_1.add(btn_2);

    btn_3 = new JButton("<html><p align=center>"+num3+"</p></html>");
    //btn_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("more_buttons\\lightblue.png"));
    //btn_3.setBorderPainted(false);  
            //btn_3.setFocusPainted(false);
            //btn_3.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
            //btn_3.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    btn_3.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14));
    btn_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));

    if(flagnum3==0)
    {   btn_3.setEnabled(false);    }

    btn_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                if(flagnum3==1)
                {
                    if(num3!=null)
                    {
                        buttonname = prodbutton.get(2).get("prodname");
                        //quantity_panel qp = new quantity_panel();
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
    panel_1.add(btn_3);



    Card.add(panel_1);
}


    public static String Capitalize(String text)
{

    String tmp[] = text.split(" ");
    int ctr=tmp.length;
    if(tmp.length>3)
    {ctr=3;}
    text="";

    for(int i=0; i<ctr; i++)
    {
        String firstLetter = tmp[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        String restLetters = tmp[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
        String converted = firstLetter + restLetters;

        if (converted.length()>6)
        {
            converted = converted.substring(0,6)+"..";
        }

        if(i!=(ctr-1))
        {
            text = text+converted+"<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            text = text+converted;
        }
    }

    return text;

  }

    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getProductsButton(int groupnum) {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prodbutton = new         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<String,String>();
            tmp.put("A","A");   
            tmp.put("B","B");
            tmp.put("C","C");
            prodbutton.add(tmp);

        return prodbutton;
            }

public static void main(String[] args) {
     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Buttonrepaint test = new Buttonrepaint();
        }
    });
}

}
```

It should be like this:

[image]

When I click the button next the blue buttons should be repainted with gray and I already have a flag for that and my only problem is that when I click the next button the buttons doesn't repaint. Nothing changed except the label Back. Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

I have posted a code there. Most likely it's like that. It's working but not the `HashMap`. Well I dunno about that but I think that would work if the `HashMap` is configured. The original `HashMap` that is in my code is connected to a database. And so. The reason why the buttons are disabled is because they don't have names which should come from the `HashMap` and since I don't know how to work it out it'll be like that. Anyway, My problem here is that, when I click next button, the names from the `ArrayList` will be change to the 2nd set of `Arrays`. The reason why I have `buttonGroup++;` is for if the button is clicked the second set of `Arrays` will be shown in the 3 buttons. And so. My problem is that when I click the next button the button names are still the same but the values did changed. That's why I want to repaint the buttons so that it would refresh.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: AFAIK there is/aren't an issue with JButton & Icon & Html together, have to debug how yout ButtonGroup works nothing else, for SSCCE/MCVE to use UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon")

Comment: What changes to `btn_1` would change it's state so that it would either require a `repaint` or change visibly in anyway?

Comment: hmmm whats (sorry) mess are code lines `buttonGroup++;` & `btn_1.repaint();` & `buttonGroup--;`, JButtons doesn't required repaint() - load all (Image)Icon to local variable or array of Icons

Comment: @mKorbel those are not a mess. it's a flag that I use in my program. `btn_1.repaint();` is what I have tried repainting my button. If it doesn't required repaint then I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can't make a runnable example simply because I don't know how to make my code short and surely those image won't show even if you run the program so how would you know if it repainted or not?

Comment: I have no idea under what conditions you buttons would change state or how that change state would occur from your code snippet...

Comment: @user3771102 again 1. JButton & Icon & Html doesn't required repaint() 2. whatever you doing with panel inside ActionListener miss notifier for LayoutManager

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have posted a runnable example but just make some changes in the `hashmap`.

Comment: Card.setVisible(true); should be last code line in public Buttonrepaint(){, and should be wrapped into invokeLater

Comment: @mKorbel can't you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Since siwng is based on the MVC model you should focus on the models instead of the ui components. I think this makes it easier, because you just change models and the ui components repaint themselfs automatically.

So I would prefer the following way, because it let you extend or change the behavior of the`Next/Back` button easily.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton buttonA = new JButton("A");
        JButton buttonB = new JButton("B");
        JButton buttonC = new JButton("C");

        ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup.add(buttonA);
        buttonGroup.add(buttonB);
        buttonGroup.add(buttonC);

        ButtonGroupVisibilityToggleChange toggleChange = new ButtonGroupVisibilityToggleChange();
        ButtonGroupToggleAction toggleAction = new ButtonGroupToggleAction(
                buttonGroup, toggleChange);

        JButton buttonGroupVisibilityButton = new JButton(toggleAction);

        contentPane.add(buttonGroupVisibilityButton);
        contentPane.add(buttonA);
        contentPane.add(buttonB);
        contentPane.add(buttonC);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

To do that I would first create an interface that represents the logic to be done on a toggle event.

```
interface ButtonGroupToggleChange {
    public boolean toggle(ButtonGroup buttonGroup, boolean actualToggleState);
}
```

And than I create an implementation to change the ButtonGroup visibility on a toggle event.

```
class ButtonGroupVisibilityToggleChange implements ButtonGroupToggleChange {

    public boolean toggle(ButtonGroup buttonGroup, boolean actualToggleState) {
        boolean nextVisibleState = !actualToggleState;
        Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = buttonGroup.getElements();
        while (buttons.hasMoreElements()) {
            AbstractButton abstractButton = buttons.nextElement();
            abstractButton.setVisible(nextVisibleState);
            Container parent = abstractButton.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.revalidate();
            }
        }

        return nextVisibleState;
    }
}
```

And finally I create an `Action` that handles the toggle state and executes the `ButtonGroupChange`

```
class ButtonGroupToggleAction extends AbstractAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1345619745031378545L;

    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
    private boolean toggleState = true;
    private String toggleOnName = "Hide";
    private String toogleOffName = "Show";

    private ButtonGroupToggleChange buttonGroupToggleChange;

    public ButtonGroupToggleAction(ButtonGroup buttonGroup,
            ButtonGroupToggleChange buttonGroupToggleChange) {
        this.buttonGroup = buttonGroup;
        this.buttonGroupToggleChange = buttonGroupToggleChange;
        executeToggleButtonChange();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        executeToggleButtonChange();
    }

    private void executeToggleButtonChange() {
        toggleState = buttonGroupToggleChange.toggle(buttonGroup, toggleState);
        setToggleName(toggleState);
    }

    public String getToggleOnName() {
        return toggleOnName;
    }

    public void setToggleOnName(String toggleOnName) {
        this.toggleOnName = toggleOnName;
        setToggleName(toggleState);
    }

    public String getToogleOffName() {
        return toogleOffName;
    }

    public void setToogleOffName(String toogleOffName) {
        this.toogleOffName = toogleOffName;
        setToggleName(toggleState);
    }

    private void setToggleName(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            putValue(Action.NAME, toggleOnName);
        } else {
            putValue(Action.NAME, toogleOffName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: agree but why not use JToggleButton and to test just for isSelected (rather than your ButtonGroupToggleAction), and OP has an issue with add JComponent at runtime, then everything messed up together

Comment: I didn't use a `JToggleButton` because the OP didn't use it. I think that the OP doesn't want the buttoon to stay pressed if it is in selected state. Nevertheless one might use the `ToggleButtonModel`.

Comment: @RenéLink Thank you for your answer but I'm good with using flags.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button "Next", the `ActionListener` registered to this button will be called.

This is the registered `ActionListener` (your code):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        buttonGroup++;

        if(prodbutton!=null)
        {
            btnGroup3.setText("Back");
            prodbutton.clear();
            stat=1;
            btn_1.repaint(); // button here should refresh
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("EMPTY!!!!!");
            buttonGroup--;
            stat=0;
        }
    }
```

In this you make no changes to the "blue" buttons (`btn_1`), so it doesn't matter if you repaint them or not, they will be (re)painted the same.

Comment: I just quoted from the questioner's code. This is not my code nor it is a suggested solution - just pointing out `btn_1` isn't modified.

Comment: @icza yes I know it doesn't work that's why I'm asking what would work to repaint my buttons.

Comment: The repaint works. It's just the view of the button doesn't change because you do nothing to it. It will be repainted the same as it was before. I assume you want to change it, so change it. Do something to it. Change its icon or text or whatever you want to.